# C# WebAPI - Calling POST Method Within Controller with Model as Parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api

I can't figure out why the below calls to my "GetBatch" webapi method isn't working. I am not sure if I need to specify the route, etc. I do have other HttpPost methods but note that I am specifically trying to call the method I defined below.

What can I do to fix? The URL should be correct because different actions do get called. Thank you for your time.

Javascript:

```
var accountGetBatchURL = '@HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)@Url.Content("~/")api/Account/GetBatch';

function () {
    'use strict';
    var lastColumns = oTable.context[0].aoColumns;
    var lastSearch = oTable.context[0].aoPreSearchCols;
    var suppliedSearchParameters = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < lastSearch.length; ++i) {
        if (lastSearch[i].sSearch !== "") {
            suppliedSearchParameters.push({ "column": lastColumns[i].mData, "value": lastSearch[i].sSearch });
        }
    }
    var dataToSend = { 'searchParameters': suppliedSearchParameters };
    $.ajax({
        url: accountGetBatchURL,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            bootbox.alert("There was a problem with sending the search parameters to the service for processing. Extended information: Error Number: " + textStatus + " Error Thrown: " + errorThrown);
        },
        success: function (json) {
            bootbox.alert("Successfully sent search parameters to LMS Search service!")
        }
    });
}
```

C# Model Code:

```
public class AccountSearchDTO
{
    public AccountSearchParameterDTO[] searchParameters { get; set; }
}

public class AccountSearchParameterDTO
{
    public string column { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class AccountSearchResultsDTO
{
    public int numOfRows { get; set; }
}
```

C# Account Controller Code":

```
[HttpPost]
public AccountSearchResultsDTO GetBatch([FromBody] AccountSearchDTO param)
{
    AccountSearchResultsDTO results = new AccountSearchResultsDTO();
    results.numOfRows = 0;
    return results;
}
```

**EDIT**: Tried the following change to my dataToSend variable which is sent via my AJAX request but I still get a "404" error:

```
var dataToSend = { 'param': { 'searchParameters': suppliedSearchParameters} };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sending your data like

```
data: dataToSend
```

instead of

```
data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend)
```

If this does not work, how do you make sure that the request "isn't working"? What response do you see?

**Update:**

Also I see that you are constructing your data like:

```
{ 'searchParameters': suppliedSearchParameters }
```

but expecting a parameter named "param" in your action:

```
public AccountSearchResultsDTO GetBatch([FromBody] AccountSearchDTO param)
```

Could you try wrapping your data in a property named param?

```
var dataToSend = { 'param':  { 'searchParameters': suppliedSearchParameters } };
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion; see my `$.ajax()` parameters above but still no success. I am getting the following error message: `{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI '[[URL]]/Account/GetBatch'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'Account' that matches the name 'GetBatch'."}`

Comment: Thanks for the help; still the same error. My other method calls work to the same controller so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Defining the `[FromBody]` attribute to the action parameter forces the WebAPI to read simple types when binding the parameter to the call. 
See: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

This does not work for you since you are passing the class `AccountSearchDTO`.

Therefore:

```
[HttpPost]
public AccountSearchResultsDTO GetBatch(AccountSearchDTO param)
{
    AccountSearchResultsDTO results = new AccountSearchResultsDTO();
    results.numOfRows = 0;
    return results;
}
```

As long as your URL points to the correct action and you are wrapping the data correctly the call should work.

Example:

```
var data = { 'searchParameters': suppliedSearchParameters };

$.ajax({
    url: accountGetBatchURL,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: "{ param:" + JSON.stringify(data) + "}",
    ...
});
```